# Is there anyway to differentiate a value ( from the shader editor ) in Blender

Tags: shaders, mathematics

The title says it all. Is it possible? bit of a noob question though so hope any of you do not mind. Differentiation refering to getting a derivative of a value.

Comment: What do you mean by "differentiate"?

Comment: DIfferentiation of a value. getting a derivative

Comment: I think the bump node takes derivatives of all the pixels in a texture (or screen space I assume), but I'm not entirely sure how to properly extract the values.

Comment: As in “take the location in successive frames and determine the velocity”? Not possible in shader nodes but can be achieved with drivers.

Comment: Which value? .. and.. dValue/dWhat?

Comment: Differentiation of a Gradient texture for example